# Why 1 document write in Firestore costs +30 reads?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore to create a log system. The structure is:

- collection: errors

  - entry for error 1
  - entry for error 2
  - ...

I add an error like so:

```
val error = hashMapOf(
    "datetime" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    "errorMessage" to errorMessage
)

database.collection("errors")
    .add(error)
```

Then I watch at how the costs are affected by this operation.
Regarding the write count, it obviously adds 1  write operation.

The problem comes with the read operations. For some reason, executing this code causes:

- More than 30 reads
- The read count keep increasing as the time pases, even if I kill the app.

Why a write operation cost so many read operations?

Comment: Note that if you are monitoring your database through the Firebase console, the reads from  the Firebase console are included in your read count.

Comment: I was watching in the firebase website, this means that per each write, if I go to the website and have the top level collection selected, all the elements are counted as a read??

Comment: If by "I go to the website" you mean "I go to the Firebase console" (https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/), the answer is yes, the reads there are counted in your quota/count.

Comment: And each time a document is enumerated (NOT opened), this count as a read??

Comment: Yes, since it is the result of a query. There is actually no concept of «is opened»: a doc is fetched with all the fields. A query fetches all the corresponding docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that if you are monitoring/watching your database through the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/), the Firestore documents reads from the Firebase console are included in your Firestore read count/quota.