# How is read counted?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So my current charge is:

```
148 reads
13 writes
12 deletes
```

My question is, how is the *read* counted.

In my code I only got this function

```
  databaseReference
        .collection("test")
        .document(firebaseUser.uid)
        .setData({'title': '$name', 'desc': '$description'});
```

So basically I tested the function a couple of times and I am wondering why I got that high reads without ever querying the result.

The deletes come from me manually deleting these Sets on the Firebase Website.

Comment: If you have the Firebase console open showing your Firestore documents, those count as charged reads for your project. This is usually where a majority of the reads come from early in the development cycle. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229630/why-1-document-write-in-firestore-costs-30-reads/62231297#62231297

Comment: Oh I didn’t see any official statement...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you clarify?